# Segmentation fault on macOS when returning from dylib

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, rust

My Rust program loads Rust written dylibs to improve modularity. It runs smoothly on Linux, but on macOS it gets a segmentation fault when returning for the third time.

Yesterday the problem was way worse that this, on macOS it was going like this at first call:

```
rustegram(4467,0x7fffad81d340) malloc: *** error for object 0x106817040: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

During debugging, I found that the problem was with using objects as  function call parameters. They were all `String`, so converting them to `&str` solved the problem.

Now I need to pass complex values `like serde_json::value::Value` and `toml::Value`.

```
pub struct Plugin {
    name: String,
    config: TomlValue,
    plugins: Vec<Arc<Lib>>,
}

impl Plugin {
    pub fn run(&self, secret: String, body: JsonValue) -> Result<JsonValue, String> {
        if self.plugins.len() > 0 {
            // In a real program you want to cache the symbol and not do it every time if your
            // application is performance critical
            match unsafe { self.plugins[0].lib.get(b"init_bot\0") } {
                Ok(temp) => {
                    let f: Symbol<extern "C" fn(config: &TomlValue, secret: &str, body: &JsonValue) -> Result<JsonValue, String>> = temp;
                    //on mac it goes "segmentation fault" returning from the third call
                    println!("DEBUG: before");
                    let res = f(&self.config.clone(), &secret.clone(), &body.clone());
                    println!("DEBUG: after");
                    res
                },
                Err(e) => Err(format!("Error getting Symbol for {}: {}", self.name, e)),
            }
        }
        else {
            Err(format!("Lib {} not loaded", self.name))
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the called method, I've put three debugging `println!` "A" "B" and "C", one before every operation. The output is:

```
DEBUG: before
A
B
C
DEBUG: after
DEBUG: before
A
B
C
DEBUG: after
DEBUG: before
A
B
C
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Sometimes, instead of segmentation fault, it gives "Illegal instruction: 4".

For the full code, you can look at [my GitHub project](https://github.com/nappa85/Rustegram/blob/master/src/webserver/registry.rs).

Comment: Are you sure that arbitrary types can be passed through the `extern "C"` ABI? Have you read the [FFI Chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/ffi.html) of the Rust book or the [FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/)?

Comment: I'm using `extern "C"` because `extern "Rust"` isn't working, I hope that a rust-on-rust call would work

Comment: Do you link the standard library dynamically (in all your libraries, including the application)?

Comment: In all ABI questions, there are two sides: the side defining the symbol and the side using the symbol. Could you also include the code of the *defining* side?

Comment: Solved, thanks everybody

Comment: @MarcoNapetti Since you have a solution, you can write it as answer. Don't write it at the bottom of the question, otherwise this just sits around looking unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Matthieu M., I wasn't dereferencing correctly.

On lib side:

```
pub extern fn init_bot(ptr_config: *const TomlValue, secret: &str, ptr_body: *const JsonValue) -> Result<JsonValue, String>
```

On application side:

```
let f: Symbol<extern "C" fn(config: *const TomlValue, secret: &str, body: *const JsonValue) -> Result<JsonValue, String>> = temp;
f(Box::into_raw(Box::new(self.config.clone())), &secret, Box::into_raw(Box::new(body)))
```